# R: How to reposition stacked bars based on total value in a stacked barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to have my stacked bar chart positioned along the x-axis based on total value. The default positioning is based on alphabetic order.

I used the following code to plot the stacked bar chart:

```
Country1 <- c(rep("Italy" , 3) , rep("Hungary" , 3) , rep("Belgium" , 3))
Shortage1 <- rep(c("Not relevant" , "Presumably active" , "Active") , 3)
Value1 <- c(11,823,480,1083,118,147,1,285,619)
DFshortage <- data.frame(Country1, Shortage1, Value1)
```

```
ggplot(DFshortage, aes(fill=Shortage1, y=Value1, x=Country1)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

The output is as follows stacked bar chart

[image]

I would like to change the position of the bars based on total value, so the correct order should become Hungary, Italy, Belgium.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ggplot(DFshortage, aes(x=reorder(Country1, -Value1), y=Value1, fill=Shortage1)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
ggplot(DFshortage, aes(fill=Shortage1, y=Value1, x=reorder(Country1, -Value1))) +  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

Comment: This is the same answer as Magda already posted before you

Comment: Lol true, must be because I had the question open for a couple of minutes without refreshing before sending my answer.

Comment: Then I recommend that you delete or upgrade your answer as this has already been proposed